# No auto-save feature in mobile design?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, mobile-web

I wanted to ask a question from my iPod Touch on SO and did some research (looking for links) on the fly, in a new site in Safari. Sadly, Safari got this annoying 'feature' to reload an open site if you dare to ignore it for five minutes (exaggeration).
Now I thought 'Okay, not that much of a problem, I got that neat question auto-saving on SO'. Well, at least that's what I thought. After the 'Ask a question' page finished reloading, I found my nearly finished question to be nuked from existence.

So, does the mobile version not have that feature or was I just unlucky? If it does not have that feature, would it be possible to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new mobile theme will have automatic draft saving after the next deploy.

Its localStorage backed (unlike the main site draft feature, which relies on posting drafts to the server), so we shouldn't fall victim to nasty latency or connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

Local Drafts feature make use of [localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html) API. Support for localstorage was added [in Mobile Safari 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640724/html5-on-iphone-safari-data-stored-by-localstorage-does-not-always-persist-why/3525879#3525879), which has been included since iOS 3.0. Perhaps you're running an older version?

Comment: I'm running iOS 4.2.1. :/