# Mobile site allows me to bypass closed questions

Tags: bug, closed-questions

Happened on this question; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128852/auto-redirect-to-ban-page/128853#128853

I composed an answer while on the mobile site, and submitted it. It submits, except that I see a 'closed by .... 7 mins ago'. Which is strange, cos closed questions aren't receptive to answers.

Pretty big loophole, it seems.

[image]

Update: (credit @lunboks) It seems that this is a client-side restriction, which is disabled on mobile.  It can most probably be bypassed *even on the full site* using Chrome insprctor and/or Firebug.

Even though I'm an amateur programmer, I do know that such stuff done on the client side is a Very Bad Thing. I say that there should be an *extra server-side block*. If the poster gets past the clientside block via mobile site or other tomfoolery, he should get the page reloaded with 'Sorry, the post is closed &c'(iirc a similar thing happens for deleted posts). Try to keep the attempted answer somewhere there, since they may want to copy  their hard work.

The possible dupe talks about a grace period, but that's inconsistent with what the main site does(disable answer submit button on close--via websockets I guess)

It seems that if you wait long enough, trying to hack-post on a closed question gives you this:
[image]

Comment: Hmm. I've voted to re-open since I just discovered that the normal site does disable your answer button if the question is closed. (This can be bypassed, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: @lunboks thanks, updated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you started composing your answer before the question was closed, you get [up to 4 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228/incorrectly-able-to-answer-a-closed-question/44634#44634) to finish and submit it, even if it does end up being closed in the meantime.

That is most likely what happened here. When using the normal site, you get a notification that the question has been closed and answers aren't being accepted anymore, but this is a client-side restriction which I guess does not exist on the mobile site.

Comment: Is this a Meta only thing? Because I could swear that the opposite happened to me quite a few times on the main site.

Comment: @Dennis On the full site, the post heartbeat will detect when a question's been closed and disable the user's ability to post when it can, but the backend still has this grace period (though I thought it had been significantly shortened; I might be wrong on that).

Comment: @tim - "post heartbeat" - are you referring to the new [real-time-updates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) functionality?

Comment: @Lix No, the questions page has, for quite a while, sent an AJAX request every ~45 seconds after you start typing in the editor (which the draft functionality piggybacks on).

Comment: @TimStone As a 10k user you're probably aware, but I just tested this. Your answer button does get disabled, even on meta, but you can just re-enable it with Firebug or similar trickery. I'm guessing my initial answer was wrong and the mobile site does not restrict you in this way.

Comment: Aye. I imagine the mobile version doesn't bother with the client side disabling for the same reason that it uses [`localStorage` for the drafts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91230/no-auto-save-feature-in-mobile-design), since the heartbeat would consume data without the user realising it.

Comment: Yeah, I though that this was it--but didn't have a desktop to test it on via inspector.

Comment: @Tim aah _thats_ why mobile drafts don't sync with the desktop version at times (though the other way around does happen)