# Measure against frustration when question has been closed or deleted

Tags: feature-request, answers, closed-questions, deleted-questions, editor

It happened many times that I wanted to answer a question on SO. I did some research, edited a text, corrected typing errors using Microsoft Word (my English is not particularly good) and created and tested a code example. But when a wanted to post it, I could not, because the question had been closed or deleted meanwhile.

**This is very frustrating!**

Note: While working on the code example in [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) or on the text in Microsoft Word one might overlook the banner indicating the closed situation.

---

### Suggestion

My suggestion is that if the answer field was visible at the time that you opened a question, you should always be able to send your answer.

The OP can still see the answer and decide to undelete his question or users can decide to reopen the question if they find the answer valuable. In any case it would diminish the frustration.

Comment: I think this used to (still does?) happen, though that was before the live-refresh features started sneaking in

Comment: @BenBrocka: It still does, wait for my answer.

Comment: You can actually still do this on the mobile version of SO, for some reason. It really confused a few mods when I did it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Are you suggesting that mobile SO and full web version behave differently? :)

Comment: @AleksG: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/mobile-site-allows-me-to-bypass-closed-questions

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles Unbelievable :)

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles should we close the question first ;P?

Comment: @BenBrocka: Be my guest. I was expecting that one :P

Comment: Just for clarity, I am speaking of the full web version.

Comment: Hi.  I have a good answer for your question.  Please give me a few minutes to add it.

Comment: Good things take time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrectly able to answer a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228/incorrectly-able-to-answer-a-closed-question) - you have **4** hours grace period if it's not deleted, [tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 9):

<sup>Psst. [This functionality is already there for closed questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128854/178438) But please don't use it, alright?</sup>

Anyway, you ought to be able to *not answer such questions and vote-to-close*, right?

You have 13k on SO. If the system works{*}, you really should be able to *gauge question quality* by now, and be able to *accurately guess what shall be closed(or deleted)*. Questions that shall be closed should be treated just like questions which *are* closed--i.e, they *shouldn't be answered*.

So, instead of trying to answer these, cast a close vote and walk away.

Note that if you feel a post was incorrectly closed/deleted, cast a reopen/undelete vote and/or flag it.

<sup>*It doesn't. :(</sup>

Comment: If an OP deletes his question this can still happen very unexpectedly. Whether a question should be closed or not is a subjective matter. If others voted to close a question because they didn't understand it, it is not a reason for me not to answer it, if I think that I did understand the question. But the question is not closing or not closing. If I expected that the question would be closed (or even voted to do so), of cause I would not spend time in trying to answer it. What would the harm be to answer a closed question? Apparently this is possible on the mobile version.

Comment: I agree with @Olivier that there is a big difference between answering a question that we should know will be closed, and answering a question that *was a good question* but that the OP has since deleted (presumably because he figured out the answer in the interim).  In the latter case, I sympathize with Olivier, and would prefer his energy to not be in vain.

Comment: @kirk see "ast line. You can always flag for undelete. Actually, self deletions are a  problem that ought to be fixed separately. I have a feature request coming up on that (offline for the weekend, though, so it'll take time)

Comment: Sometimes, what sways a question from being closed to being reopened is that a worthwhile answer that snuck in just before the close proves that a worthwhile answer is possible. Sometimes, there are questions where it's pretty obvious a kneejerk-close will happen, but where there is something worthwhile to say - the only question being whether others will think it worthwhile.